# How can I make AdMob interstitial ad so they must press the advert to continue

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm going to be running a comp later this month in my app and I want to use adverts. What I want to do is when a member clicks a button it shows an ad, then if they click the ad to open Google Play a promo code appears. I'm using the stock code avaliable from Ad Mob for interstitials. Just wondering how to edit to show promo code only after clicking the ad.

```
public class comp extends AppCompatActivity  {
  private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
  private TextView  Pcode;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comp);
    Pcode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PromoCode);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.fullscreen_ad_unit_id));
    Button bce = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bcompenter);
    bce.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showInterstitial();

            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    StartTask();
                }
            });
        }
    });
  }

  private void showInterstitial() {
    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and restart the game.
    if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for installing using H20 Droid Apps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        StartTask();
    }
  }

  private void StartTask() {
    // Request a new ad if one isn't already loaded, hide the button, and kick off the timer.
    if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading() && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        Pcode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you are not allowed to force the users to click or interrupt app flow if not clicked as per admob T&C

Comment: thanks for that didnt know